# Return submitted POST data with Alpine.js and new FormData()

Tags: alpine.js

I'm attempting to POST some form data, using Alpine.js, to the current page which would then be used by PHP $_GET to run some functionality.

It seems to be returning the entire page in the response, rather than the form data (which then errors out due to it being invalid JSON).

How can I only return the submitted form data in the response?

```
<form
    method="post"
    action="./"
    class="form__press"
    x-on:submit.prevent="
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', 'Chris');
        fetch('./', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          console.log('Success:', result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });"
>
    <div class="field mb:15@xs">
        <label for="pressEmail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="pressEmail" autocomplete="off" required />
    </div>
    <div class="field mb:15@xs">
        <label for="pressPassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pressPassword" autocomplete="new-password" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the right answer to this is that you need your PHP backend function to return JSON with the correct content-type ("application/json").

However you can also achieve this client side since you've got all the data you want returned.

```html
<form
    method="post"
    action="./"
    class="form__press"
    x-on:submit.prevent="
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', 'Chris');
        fetch('./', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        })
        .then(() => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formData)))
        .then((result) => {
          console.log('Success:', result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });"
>
```